# How do I call some part of code again in same function?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use code again in same function without doing extra function for it.

while my `pinchGesture` is .`ended` now I want to call this codition
(as shown in code).

```
    func isParformPinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer, forTag tag:Int, protectedTag protact:Int){

        if protact == tag{
            return
         }

    //THIS PART CALL AGAIN 

        if isPinching(forView: imageArray[tag],inView: recognizer.view!,  fromTransformation: recognizer.scale) {                                
             imageArray[tag].transform = imageArray[tag].transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)                     
         }

      if recognizer.state == .ended{
          // call again above condition

       }
    }
```

Comment: you can do a for-loop around something, if you want to call it several times, is that what you mean?

Comment: @choli question is updated with more details.

Comment: I would have done the exact same as bunty did, after i saw your updated question, try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve, but I guess what you are looking for is the notion of **closure** ( equivalent of the Objective-C **block** ):

```
func isParformPinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer, forTag tag:Int, protectedTag protact:Int){

        if protact == tag{
            return
         }

       // Declare your block: it's kind of a function-variable
       let myBlock = {
           if isPinching(forView: imageArray[tag],inView: recognizer.view!,  fromTransformation: recognizer.scale) {                                
             imageArray[tag].transform = imageArray[tag].transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)                     
           }
        }

       // Execute your block whenever you need to
       myBlock()    

       if recognizer.state == .ended  {
          // call again above condition
          myBlock()
       }
}
```

I strongly invite you to read more about closures as it is a powerful, yet not that easy to manipulate, feature: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

EDIT: as **Grimxn** pointed out in the comments, an even cleaner way to do that would be to use a local function:

```
func isParformPinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer, forTag tag:Int, protectedTag protact:Int){

        if protact == tag{
            return
         }

       // Declare your local function
       func myLocalFunction() {
           if isPinching(forView: imageArray[tag],inView: recognizer.view!,  fromTransformation: recognizer.scale) {                                
             imageArray[tag].transform = imageArray[tag].transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)                     
           }
        }

       // Execute your function whenever you need to
       myLocalFunction()    

       if recognizer.state == .ended  {
          // call again above condition
          myLocalFunction()
       }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a closure, but why not simply use a local function instead? i.e. replace `let myBlock =` with `func myBlock()` ...

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a local function instead I guess ^^. It's just that OP asked "I want to use code again in same function without doing extra function for it.". The other thing is that implementing a local function to perform such a specific task looks kind of dirty.. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: why on earth would a named function as opposed to an anonymous function (a closure) be "dirty"! :)

Comment: You're right, that's questionable ^^. But here, I'd say that I don't really like to declare a 1 line function with 4 arguments, that's gonna be used one time only.
Depends on the situation of course.

Comment: Sorry to go on about it - but you *don't* need arguments - just literally replace "let myBlock =" with "func myBlock()" - no big deal!!!

Comment: Haha no worries, you're right. I correctly read "local function" but I thought "global function". My bad, you're totally right.

Answer (score 5):

```
func isParformPinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer, forTag tag:Int, protectedTag protact:Int){

    if protact == tag{
        return
    }

    do {
        //THIS PART CALL AGAIN

        if isPinching(forView: imageArray[tag],inView: recognizer.view!,  fromTransformation: recognizer.scale) {
            imageArray[tag].transform = imageArray[tag].transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
        }

    }while(recognizer.state == .ended);  // if true, call again above condition

}
```